# SRTM data represented in 3D using Unity Terrain

Tags: unity, terrain, terrain-rendering, heightmap

I am new to using Terrain height maps in Unity.

I'm trying to use real-world terrain height data, using sources including:

- The [US Geological Survey](https://www.usgs.gov/) (files like N24E054.hgt)
- Google Maps (SRTM hdr files, tfw files, and tif files)

I want to import this high definition terrain data into a Unity terrain.

In Unity, it seems like terrain can only import Raw data representation.

How can I use an hgt file to shape a Unity Terrain?

Comment: Have you ever looked at [this](https://unity3d.college/2017/07/17/importing-real-world-terrain-unity-free-terrain-party/)?

Comment: i used an application called L3dt, which can import many format of heightmap and export in many including RAW

Comment: It is also possible to build your own mesh, piece by piece, from the .hgt. But you'd have to parse the data yourself, and whether you'd want to do that, I don't know. But this would provide a lot of control over the end result. See [the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html).

Answer (score 1):

i used an application called L3dt, which can import many format of heightmap and export in many including RAW

free version here (you can also email request a free trial of the Pro Edition):
http://www.bundysoft.com/L3DT/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

I used terrain.party website to get the maps. It works pretty well. You feed it location coodinates and returns the maps.

Gimp is a nice program to use to view and export the file to Raw.

Then you import the raw heightmap to use as terrain.

Comment: didnt realise you could just use Gimp.. nice! :D

Answer (score 0):

Uset [VTBuilder](http://vterrain.org/Doc/VTBuilder/overview.html) and then export to your prefered format:

> Export elevation grids to ArcInfo ASCII Grid, GeoTIFF, TerraGen, BMP,
>   STM, MSI Planet, VRML ElevationGrid, RAW, ChunkLOD (.chu), PNG 16-bit,
>   3TX, and more.